# password manager to replace Revelation

Tags: password, keepass

The password manager Revelation is [apparently missing from disco/19.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=revelation&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). I imagine it was retired because it got no updates for a while.

I have been using it for years now, so I have to look for a replacement. I would prefer something reasonably future-proof, eg with a database format that is somehow standardized and perhaps supported by multiple interfaces. And of course FOSS.

My needs are simple:

1. generate random passwords,
2. save passwords for various purposes,
3. be able to search and browse passwords (fuzzy matching optional)

Organizing them in folders/directories is optional.

I did some research and it looks like the Keepass 2 format is supported by multiple programs, eg `keepass2` and `keepassxc`. Are there any other alternatives I should consider?

Comment: I think KeePass is the one you need.

Answer (score 2):

The package has returned in 21.04.

Download from 21.04:

```sh
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/revelation/revelation_0.5.4-2_amd64.deb
```

Install dependencies:

```sh
sudo apt-get install python3-pycryptodome python3-pwquality python3-cracklib
```

Install package:

```sh
sudo dpkg -i revelation_0.5.4-2_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

Revelation 0.5.0 has been available for just a week now, which I guess is why it didn't make it into Ubuntu 20.04 / Mint 20. The developers have been doing a lot of work on it, mainly for a new Python version I believe. I had it working and opening my wallet on a fresh Mint 20 install last night.

The source is available here https://revelation.olasagasti.info/download.php
you need to unpack into a download folder, then to build it dependencies need to be installed:-

```
sudo aptitude install libgtk-3-dev python-gi-dev libpwquality-dev python3-pwquality
```

You can then do the usual

```
./configure

make

sudo make install
```

Unfortunately there appears to be a bug in the current Ubuntu/Mint 20 install so I contacted the Revelation maintainer to ask how to get it to work. The answer I received was to start it from a terminal using

```
PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ revelation
```

which works for me. I asked for further advice from the Ubuntu list. I don't have the Mint 20 computer here but when I can get to it again I'll try adding the `PYTHONPATH` to `/etc/environment`. Hopefully Revelation will then start up properly from the graphical start menu.

BTW I know nothing about Python. These days I just do a little C/C++ programming for hobby purposes for myself.